# django graphs with graphos says Template doesnot exist

Tags: django, graph

After looking at many options to render graph using django i thought graphos might be the best option , however when trying to run it using there very basic example i am getting error of Template doesnot exist
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    graphos/flot.html

I used the very basic code as from their documentation here https://agiliq.com/docs/django-graphos/flot.html :

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    queryset = Pockets.objects.all()
    print "query set is ",queryset
    data_source = ModelDataSource(queryset,
                              fields=['pocket_name', 'sum_pocket'])
    chart = flot.LineChart(data_source)
    print "chart is ",chart
    context_dict.update({'chart': chart})
return render_to_response('a/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

in my index.html i am using

```
<div>
    <!--for graph stuff-->
    {{ chart.as_html }}
        </div>
```

but still getting error TemplateDoesNotExist at /a/
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    graphos/flot.html

couldnt figure out what could be the problem , documents doesnt say what is missing .
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 8):

Check your settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS section that you have included 'graphos'.
It should look something like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'graphos',
)
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. I think anyone who is experienced with Django will know exactly what the issue is, but since I'm a newbie it took me a few minutes of banging my head against the wall to figure it out.

Here is the solution:
Graphos includes a folder called "templates". The contents of this folder should be placed in the templates folder for your django project.

Answer (score 0):

A github issue explicitly states you do not have to add graphos to your INSTALLED_APPS:

https://github.com/agiliq/django-graphos/issues/90

I think Paul Greene is correct - you have to add the Templates directory to your app. This is not listed in the Tutorial (yet?) but I think this is required to get Graphos to work.